# Inserting element into array using c#

Tags: c#, arrays, insertion, indexoutofrangeexception

```
        int[] arr = {4,3,6,7,9,12};

        int n = arr.Length;
        n = n + 1;

        for (int i =n;i>2;i--) { 
        arr[i-1] = arr[i-2];

        }

        arr[0] = 4;
```

The above code returning

> indexOutOfRangeexception.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why don't you use a [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) instead?

Comment: arr.Length is 6; you assign it to n, n is now 6, n is n + 1, n is now 7, in your loop i = n which is 7, arr[i-1] is arr[6] and, arr[6] doesnt exist, that is why you get indexOutOfRange Exception, and you should use lists if you want to edit

Comment: inserting an element on 1st index @S.Akbari

Comment: I can use list but I need to find how insert an element  in array

Comment: @vnuthaya You can't with an array, you need to use a `List<int>` instead.

Comment: @sergenp if arr.Length is 7 ,last index is 6 right!!. there will be a arr[6]. Am I wrong!!

Comment: Arrays are a fixed length data structure.  If you want to "add" a value you actually have to create a new array.  In fact that's what List does behind the scenes for you.

Comment: @vnuthaya arr length is not 7, it is 6, maybe you forgot to add another element to it?

Comment: @vnuthaya, please let us know what are your requirements? You can't resize an array in C#, this collection type has a fixed length. If you want a collection that can be resized use List, LinkedList or any other collection classes that are based on List. Are you trying to _replace_ an element? Shift elements? Please describe your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int n = arr.Length //n=6
n=n+1 //n=7
for(int i=n;i>2;i--){ //i=7
  arr[i-1] //arr[6]
```

While clearly the last element is arr[5].
In C# arrays are of constant length, you can't change them, the only way to do that is to create a new array, or a better solution would be using List<>

Comment: Is it possible with C or Java

Answer (score 0):

Of course it will because of these

```
n = n + 1; // n = 7
for (int i =n;i>2;i--) {  //Assining 7 to i  
arr[i-1] = arr[i-2]; // trying to access arr[6] which is not valid
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array is of `Length` 6 starting from 0.

In `for` loop i becomes 7 and `arr[7-1] = arr[6]` is out of range, maximum is `arr[5]` ie:

```
arr[0]
arr[1]
arr[2]
arr[3]
arr[4]
arr[5]
```